# setting button size in case of custom login facebook button in andorid

Tags: android, facebook

In case of custom facebook login button after all possibilities (setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds, fb:login_text="", fb:logout_text="") I am still facing image size problem[image]

where as before facebook implementation it looks like the image below, its not getting the wrap content properties of custom image how can I do it? [image]

xml

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        fb:login_text=""
        fb:logout_text="" />
```

code

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);      

authButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fb_btn);    

authButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Image is not enough to know your problem.

Comment: I added xml and class code

Comment: I think the problem in loginButton is android:layout_height="wrap_content" change all to fix number